# remove outliers from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, outliers

I used below codes to identify outliers on different columns:

```
outliers_x1 <- boxplot(mydata$x1, plot=FALSE)$out
outliers_x4 <- boxplot(mydata$x4, plot=FALSE)$out
outliers_x6 <- boxplot(mydata$x6, plot=FALSE)$out
```

Now, how can I remove those outliers from the dataset by one code?

Comment: Could you share `dput(df)`. Easier to help you then

Comment: What do you mean "remove"? Set to `NA`? Delete all rows where any column has an outlier?

Comment: x1, x4, x6 are the names of columns. Those codes detect the index of rows of the outliers. I want to delete those detected rows.

Comment: Your code detects the values, not the indexes

Answer (score 0):

This will set any outlier values to `NA`, and then optionally remove all rows where any column contains an outlier. Works with arbitrary number of columns.

Uses `data.table` for convenience.

```
library(data.table)
library(matrixStats)
##
#   create sample data
#
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100), x3=rnorm(100))
##
#   incorporate possible outliers
#
dt[sample(100, 5), x1:=10*x1]
dt[sample(100, 5), x2:=10*x2]
dt[sample(100, 5), x3:=10*x3]
##
#    you start here...
#    remove all rows where any column contains an outlier
#
indx <- sapply(dt, \(x) !(x %in% boxplot(x, plot=FALSE)$out))
dt[as.logical(rowProds(indx))]
```

In the above, `indx` is a matrix with three logical columns. Each element is `TRUE` unless the corresponding column contained an outlier in that row. We use `rowProds(...)` from the `matrixStats` package to multiply ( `&` ) the 3 rows together. Unfortunately this converts everything numeric (1, 0), so we have to convert back to logical to use as an index into `dt`.

```
##
#   replaces outliers with NA in each column
#
dt.melt <- melt(dt[, id:=seq(.N)], id='id')
dt.melt[, ol:=(value %in% boxplot(value, plot=FALSE)$out), by=.(variable)]
dt.melt[(ol), value:=NA]
result <- dcast(dt.melt, id~variable)[, id:=NULL]
##
#   remove all rows where any column contains an outlier
#
na.omit(result)
```

In the code above we add an `id` column, then `melt(...)` so all other columns are in one column (`value`) with a second column (`variable`) indicating the original source column. Then we apply the `boxplot(...)` algorithm group-wise (by `variable`) to produce an `ol` column indicating an outlier. Then we set any `value` corresponding to `ol == TRUE` to `NA`. Then we re-convert to your original wide format with `dcast(...)` and remove the `id`.

It's a bit roundabout but this melt - process - dcast pattern is common when processing multiple columns like this.

Finally, `na.omit(result)` will remove any rows which have `NA` in any of the columns. If that's what you want it's simpler to use the first approach.

Comment: I proceeded as below. But I dont know how to delete them:                                                                                                   
 out_ind1 <- which(pl$x1 %in% c(outliers_x1))           
 out_ind4 <- which(pl$x4 %in% c(outliers_x4))                                                             
out_ind6 <- which(pl$x6 %in% c(outliers_x6))                                                
ox1=pl[out_ind1,]
ox4=pl[out_ind4,]
ox6=pl[out_ind6,]

Comment: data_without_outliers=pl[-c("ox1", "ox4", "ox6"), ]  Error in -c("ox1", "ox4", "ox6") : invalid argument to unary operator